# How to find related rows in sql

Tags: sql

I have a table that contains many rows such as:

```
id      file
-----------------------------------
1       7-Zip Portable 4.42
2       7-Zip Portable 4.42 Rev 2
3       7-Zip Portable 4.57
4       7-Zip Portable 4.62
5       7-Zip Portable 4.64 
6       SeaMonkey Portable 2.35 
7       SeaMonkey Portable 3 
8       SeaMonkey Portable 4.11
```

I want related rows when search for "7-Zip Portable 4.42"

```
id      file
-----------------------------------
1       7-Zip Portable 4.42
2       7-Zip Portable 4.42 Rev 2
3       7-Zip Portable 4.57
4       7-Zip Portable 4.62
5       7-Zip Portable 4.64
```

How can I do it in sql ?

Comment: Have a look at `LIKE` operator.

Comment: I thought I understood your question before you edited it, but now I don't. What relates `7-Zip Portable 4.62` to "7-Zip Portable 4.42"?

Comment: @XakirKMoideen I see you never accepting answers. If you find correct answer you should mark It as correct by clicking `V` in top-left of answer.

Comment: can i search 3 word "7-Zip + Portable + 4.42" or "7-Zip + Portable + files"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an answer

```
SELECT * FROM `post` WHERE `title` LIKE '%7-Zip%' OR '%Portable%' OR '%4.42%'
```

Comment: The only filter that makes sense from your query is `'7-Zip%'`. Filter `'Portable%'` is irrelevant, because there are no posts that start with `Portable`, same thing with `'4.42%'`. Did you mean to use `'%Portable%'` instead?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `LIKE`

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE file LIKE '7-Zip Portable%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LIKE` with wildcard `%` in following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TblName
WHERE file LIKE '7-Zip Portable 4.42%'
```

Comment: i need a result for 7-Zip Portable 4.42